# how to always allow microphone usage in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, camera, microphone

My development server wont allow https so i can not use always allow option to have default permission for microphone and camera.
any suggestion for how to always allow microphone usage in Google Chrome ?